# How to install JayDeBeApi on Python 3.X

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in python. For my current project I need to import jaydebeapi.I'm using python3.6.3 on Windows 7
So I used following command from my command prompt

```
pip install JayDeBeApi
```

But it is throwing error message which you can find in this image
[image: JayDeBeApi installation error]

Can you please suggest me the correct way to install it?

Comment: It says it right in the dialog: "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required"...

Comment: I'm not much of a windows guy but from the error it seems you need to get microsoft visual c++ build tools (http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools). Have you tried that?

Comment: After installing visual c++ build & running the pip install command I'm not seeing any error message.It is showing that successfully installed Jpype1-0.6.2 but while I'm using `import jaydebeapi` then I'm getting error message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jaydebeapi'`